# Is there any other way to provide portal login(default portal login url in salesforce) url to open it without hardcoding in code using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, salesforce

I have written a selenium script to open the default portal to log in. I have successfully been able to log in by hardcoding portal login URL.
Eg:
String portal_Url = "My_default_portal_Login_url";
driver.get(portal_Url);

But, is there any way to get the portal URL dynamically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish? Change URL when running from a pipeline/Jenkins job? Based on previous actions? From a step in a Gherkin file?